# Пароніми духовий і духовний: як і коли вживати?

Tags: вживання-слів

Завжди вважала, що духовий стосується оркестру, інструменту, а духовний - релігійної та психічної сфери. Однак професор В.Максимович чітко розмежовує ці терміни, за ним духовний стосується тільки церковно-релігійного життя. У творах Франка є духова праця, духові інтереси, а в Лесі Українки вже духовна рівновага. Кому з класиків довіряти, і яке слово вжити стосовно відродження держави?

Comment: Вірогідно, у Франка наголос падає на у - дУхові справи, інтереси... щодо оркестру - духовИй. До того ж, духовА піч. https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Те вживання слова "дух**о**вий", що ви бачите у Франка та Максимовича, можна знайти у:

1. [Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9)

> Духо́вий, а, е. Духовный, къ духу относящійся. Якась незвичайна
>   сміливість і духова міць. Мир. ХРВ. 4.

2. [Словник української мови: в 11 тт.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9):

> ДУХО́ВИЙ, а, е, діал. Духовний (у 1 знач.). Товариського, духового
>   життя,.. спільних духових інтересів [у гімназистів] майже не було
>   (Фр., IV, 1950, 242); Вона належала до тих щасливих, котрі не
>   старіються скоро, на котрих лиці відбивалося однак духове життя (Коб.,
>   І, 1956, 99).

Це слово з наголосом на другий склад зазначається у СУМі як діалектичне. Незважаючи на те, що це словник радянський, у повсякденному житті сьогодні дух**о**вий навіть у західних реґіонах України буде важко (хоч, може, саме завдяки впливу таких явищ як цей словник так і сталося).

Тому ви цілком правильно розумієте, що

Духов**и**й:

> 1. Який приводиться в дію вдуванням струменя повітря (про музичні інструменти).
>
> **Духови́й орке́стр; Духова́ му́зика** — оркестр, що складається з духових
>   інструментів. Опівдні десь неподалеку заграв духовий оркестр (Збан.,
>   Єдина, 1959, 211); А там [біля клубу] уже світло й народ прибува, І
>   весело музика гра духова (Мур., Лірика, 1954, 32).
>
> 2. Який діє за допомогою нагрітого повітря.

Дух**о**вний:

> 1. Зв’язаний з внутрішнім психічним життям людини, моральним світом її.
> 2. Стос. до релігії, церкви, належний їм; протилежне світський.

Comment: Додам, що «Російсько-український словник» А. Кримського та С. Єфремова (1924–1933) дає у слові [_духовий_](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=духовий&dicts=1&highlight=on) (у значенні «духовний») подвійний наголос: _ду́хо́вий_ (про це ще Oksana Çeliker зазначила в [своєму коментарі](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3043#comment5474_3043)).